# How to reverseOrder a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?

Tags: java

I'm making program in `java` and I don't know what kind of `Map` would be best to use here. Maybe `Tree`, `Hash`, `Map`,`...`?

```
degree.put("a",5);
degree.put("b",2);
degree.put("c",4);
degree.put("d",2);
degree.put("e",3);
degree.put("f",5);
```

Now I have to Sort this list according to given Integer values

Sorted Map Should be :

`{a=5, f=5, c=4, e=4, b=4, d=2}`

Could someone give `code` example?

Comment: *"Could someone show full code example"* - You.

Comment: asking for a full code example is never a good idea. Ask for what you are stuck on but try to do things on your own.

Comment: Ehhhhhh no. I don't think so.

Comment: You need to make use of Comparator interface. You can read about this here. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: Googling "how to sort a map by value in java" should suit your needs.

Comment: It looks like you want a List<Degree>, and not a Map<String, Integer>.

Comment: There are n no. of answers posted in other blogs. Spent some time googling the question. Still if you any problem you can put it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
private static HashMap sortByComparator(HashMap unsortMap) {
            HashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();         
            try {       
                List list = new LinkedList(unsortMap.entrySet());

                // sort list based on comparator
                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
                    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                        return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                                .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
                    }
                });

                // put sorted list into map again
                //LinkedHashMap make sure order in which keys were inserted

                for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sortedMap;
        }
```

if u want it in descending order then change return statement to `return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue()) .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());`

Comment: No it doesn't work it shorts in wrong direction like:
2 3 4, but not:
4 3 2

Comment: try interchange o1 and o2 in return statement like this.. 

`return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
                                .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());`

if u want to sort in descending order

Comment: did you try this? was it helpful?